# Windows fails to start after RAM upgrade

Tags: windows-7, memory, bios, upgrade

I have a alienware m11x r2 and I recently bought some new RAM for it. However after installing it, when windows boots up a "Windows fails to start" page appears. I am then giving the option to repair windows, but this just loads a screen that says "windows is loading files." This does nothing though, and it simply reboots. I'm thinking that I might have bought RAM that is not compatible with my system.

I bought 2 sticks of DDR3 1600 1.5V RAM and I believe that previous RAM was DDR3 800 1.35V. Is this the reasons it does not seem to take the new RAM? I thought I read that in the BIOS you can set values for RAM speed and voltage, but there are no such options - though the BIOS does recognize the new RAM.

Is there a way to make this new RAM compatible, or do I need to buy another kind? Thanks!

Comment: You need to check your manual to verify how much memory your computer supports.  You buying memory twice as fast and which requires 200 mv more then your other ram is a problem.  I would just return the memory since you bought the wrong speed.

Comment: Test with one stick at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you trying to boot into an OS installation before you verify that the new RAM works  correctly? That's a recipe for disaster and is likely to corrupt your OS installation. Do not make any attempt to load Windows until you *know* your hardware is reliable.

Test with [memtest86+](http://memtest.org).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem on a Windows 7 32 bit system after swapping RAM sticks (two pairs of identical 4GB sticks), because the system was only recognizing 4GB out of the 8GB.

Windows wouldnt boot at all.  Nothing worked for me.Nothing worked for me.

Long story short: i had a 32 bit system and installing a 64 bit version was the only solution that worked for me.

[Here is my complete solution](https://superuser.com/a/1171587/156771)