# Windows 7 Keeps Rebooting after RAM Upgrade

Tags: windows-7, memory, hardware-failure, reboot

My Notebook comes with a 4GB RAM (2x2GB) (Sony Vaio vpcea46fm)

I am Upgrading to 8GB (2x4GB) memory, but after i installed the new ships, windows keeps rebooting. If i return the old RAM everything goes back to normal.

How to troubleshoot such a problem?

Comment: Seems like you have troubleshooted the problem. You've determined that the new memory chips are defective.

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't the laptop like beep on start up if the ram are defective?!

Comment: Did you go into BIOS to see if the memory is recognized? According to the specs it requires DDR3-1066MHz modules. Is that what you purchased? ESD (Electrostatic Discharge) can damage computer components. Did you properly ground yourself when handling the modules?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem on a Windows 7 32 bit system ("and herein lies the rub", WS) after swapping RAM sticks (two pairs of identical 4GB sticks) because  os was only recognizing 4GB, not 8GB.  After doing so, Windows would restart upon boot.

NOTE: i have a triple boot machine (2 windows 7, none working, alongside ubuntu 14) and ubuntu was running perfectly well throughout the process.

Repair was unable to restore.  CMOS default was unable to restore Windows 7 to working order.  `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot` did not solve the problem.  Booting in Ubuntu, I reconstructed GRUB.  Still no results.  Restoring former sticks did not work.  Booting with one stick did not work (even changing slots and sticks).

Eventually I installed a 64bit version on top of one of the 32bit windows 7.  That worked and the new 64bit OS is working, though the other 32bit version still does not work and will be removed.

If your laptop is equipped with a core i3 380M, consider upgrading to a 64bit system.  Check:

[Check this vaio 64bit driver link](http://sonyvaiodriver.com/sony-vaio-vpcea46fm-windows-7-64-bit-drivers/)